Detect bluetooth pairing on Android
I am trying to make a feature that detects if your phone has connected to another device via Bluetooth, be it headphones, a car, another phone, etc. And if a device is detected there should be a response.
I have made a separate Bluetooth receiver class that checks for BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED and based on that I should receive a message in the logs, though I do not. All the needed permissions are included, the receiver class is properly initiated in the MainActivity, and yet no response. What could be the issue?
class BluetoothReceiver(
    private val onBluetoothConnected: () -> Unit,
    private val onBluetoothDisconnected: () -> Unit,
) : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.d("BluetoothReceiver", "Received intent: ${intent.action}")
        when (intent.action) {
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED -> {
                Log.d("BluetoothReceiver", "Bluetooth device connected")
                onBluetoothConnected()
            }

            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED -> {
                Log.d("BluetoothReceiver", "Bluetooth device disconnected")
                onBluetoothDisconnected()
            }
        }
    }
}

And this is how I handle it in my main activity;
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    val filter = IntentFilter().apply {
        addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)
        addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED)
    }
    registerReceiver(bluetoothReceiver, filter)
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    unregisterReceiver(bluetoothReceiver)
}

private fun setupBluetoothReceiver(): BluetoothReceiver {
    return BluetoothReceiver(
        onBluetoothConnected = { toggleSilentMode(true) },
        onBluetoothDisconnected = { toggleSilentMode(false) }
    )
}

For context toggleSilentMode is a method that enables DND on the smartphone and does some other visual changes.

Are you sure you have requested and declared all permissions? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice#ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED
